# Question ban problem

Tags: support, closed-questions, post-ban

I am having a problem in Stack Overflow. A while ago, I got into a question ban because one of my questions were marked as too broad. After that, I did everything I could to get out of it. I offered many answers to questions, 2 of which were marked as the answer, and I even answered some of my own unanswered questions. This clearly outweighs my 1 "too broad" question, but the question ban has still not lifted. It has been like this for several months now. Help please!

Comment: That's not the only question that factors into it. You have two deleted questions, one of which is also closed, and three negatively scored questions on top of that. Then you have zero positively scored questions. That doesn't sound *too* horrible so I can't imagine it'll take you much longer to get unblocked if you keep providing good answers.

Comment: If I have an answer that is updated but not marked as an answer, does it still count?

Comment: It looks clear now

Comment: Aha.  Someone just accepted one of my answers now so that must be it. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: I have asked several good technical questions. I have great discussions on those questions too. But yet, people are not making plus one to those questions. Isn't this bad thing for the people answers, as the OP probably has thought a lot and then asked the question hoping to get a good answer.

Comment: Check out my last two questions. For any technical guy, those two questions are awesome, and properly asked but yet they didn't receive any positive response. Is this my fault that I ask only the questions from the field I am into. Algorithm should also consider this approach before applying the question ban

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As animuson noted:

> That's not the only question that factors into it. You have two deleted questions, one of which is also closed, and three negatively scored questions on top of that. Then you have zero positively scored questions. That doesn't sound *too* horrible so I can't imagine it'll take you much longer to get unblocked if you keep providing good answers.

The system looks at your entire history of asking questions on the site. You don't get banned for *one* question that wasn't well-received, you get banned for *a history* of questions where many were not seen as useful and appropriate.

When you encounter a ban or a warning about your question history, go through *all* of your past questions and look for anything you can do to improve them.

Comment: But my previous questions are closed and even if I modify them , it wont be visible to the community. I dont know what to do. And I am in an endless loop. Much of my questions are downvoted. If I want to ask questions , I modify the entire downvoted question into a new question. So the answers and comments on the post donot makes sense with the question. (I get more downvotes for changing the entire question). And thus , I am stuck in a endless loop. Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/61692735/12982627

Comment: This makes no sense. I've been a member for over 8 years. DO you REALLY expect me to troll through all the old questions I've ever asked and update them just so I can ask a new question? You guys ask too much of my time. Old questions should matter less and less the older they are until eventually they have no bearing on my current status.

Comment: @Anthony is right. And what Stackoverflow is inadvertently promoting here is for people like myself to just go make a new account to be able to get out of Stackoverflow jail. And where are my deleted posts and how can I make those better? I better edit this comment for fear of the thought police.